# This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.2

Tags: python, html, css, xml, django

When using the following code in django template:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
<link href="http://52.11.183.14/static/wiki/bootstrap/css/wiki-bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://52.11.183.14/static/wiki/bootstrap/css/simple-sidebar.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<title> Profile - Technology βιβλιοθήκη </title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">


    {% for p in profiles %}
     {{p}}
    {% endfor %}


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I receive the following error:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
```

Why? And what can I do to fix it?

Solved: by change HttpResponse on render_to_response

```
   my_context={'profiles': profiles}
   c = RequestContext(request,{'profiles': profiles})
   return render_to_response('wiki/profile.html',
                      my_context,
                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
   #return HttpResponse(t.render(c), content_type="application/xhtml+xml")
```

Comment: How can we reproduce this error?

Comment: skip {% for p in profiles %}
     {{p}}
    {% endfor %}

Comment: @AndreyEremchuk where did you see the error? simply opening HTML file in browser should never produce such error...

Comment: i use django template processor/ simple open in browser

Answer (score 1):

You must replace your content html tag with this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html dir="rtl" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```